# Bootstrap divider issues

Tags: html, css

i'm want to do something like in this picture https://s1.postimg.org/1u8qkhey4v/Untitled-1.png

i tried to do something similar but i'm more curious about how i can do that horizontal line between them

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <a href="#"><img class="item1"  src="img/item1.png" alt="item1"></a>
                <a href="#"><img class="item1"  src="img/item1.png" alt="item1"></a>              
             </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h2 class="title">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</h2>
                <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nec lectus felis. Sed nec dignissim felis, id tempor turpis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>


                <h2 class="title">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</h2>
                <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nec lectus felis. Sed nec dignissim felis, id tempor turpis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <a href="#"><img class="item1"  src="img/item1.png" alt="item1"></a>
              <a href="#"><img class="item1"  src="img/item1.png" alt="item1"></a>             
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
              <h2 class="title">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</h2>
              <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nec lectus felis. Sed nec dignissim felis, id tempor turpis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>


              <h2 class="title">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</h2>
              <p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi nec lectus felis. Sed nec dignissim felis, id tempor turpis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>


          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a border to the bottom of a div.

```
.border-bottom {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Then add the class border to the first `col-md-6`

```
<div class="col-md-6 border-bottom">
....
</div>
```